# JS: What is the use of having a 'live' list with querySelector or getElementsByTagName vs. non-live querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

I understand that a live list allows the variable holding the nodes to be updated if another is added or removed but I'm struggling to think of an example of how this would be beneficial vs. using a non-live list (querySelectorAll)?

Comment: `querySelector` doesn't return a live list, it doesn't return a list at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows you to write the variable assignment just once, rather than having to update it whenever you change the DOM. So you can do something like:

```
var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

function processRows() {
    for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
        // do something with allRows[i]
    }
}
```

Rather than:

```
function processRows() {
    var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
        // do something with allRows[i]
    }
}
```

By itself this isn't very compelling, but if you have multiple functions that use `allRows`, you would need to repeat the assignment in each of them. The live `NodeList` allows them all to use the same list.

The implementation of live node lists uses a cache, so the list will only be recalculated the first time it's used after a DOM modification, so the cost of recalculating is amortized over all the functions.